# Why doesn't my rails app open? Even though I set up the environment variable 'SECRET_KEY_BASE' with the commands ($ heroku config:set ~, etc...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, heroku

My ruby ​​version is 2.6.6, my mysql version is 8.0.23, my mysql2 version is 0.5.3, my bundler version is 2.2.21, my rails version is 5.0.7.2, and my Xcode version is 12.5.

I use macOS Big Sur(version 11.4) and the text editor "Atom".

I'm planning to release my Rails application with the URL of HEROKU(example. https://[My APP Name].herokuapp.com).

I ran the following command.

```
$ heroku open
```

The following error occured.

```
An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.
```

I ran the following command.

```
$ heroku logs

#<RuntimeError: Missing
 `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `
config/secrets.yml`>
```

I set up two environment variables as below with this command: $ heroku config:set [ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE NAME].

```
$ heroku config:set DATABASE_USERNAME=****
```

```
$ heroku config:set DATABASE_PASSWORD=****
```

My config/secrets.yml file is something like belows.

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

I ran the following command.

```
$ bundle exec rake secret

GENERATED_CODE
```

I ran the following command.

```
$ heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED_CODE

Setting SECRET_KEY_BASE and restarting ⬢ [My APP Name]... done, v24
SECRET_KEY_BASE: GENERATED_CODE
```

I set up the environment variable `SECRET_KEY_BASE` as below.

```
$ vi /etc/profile
```

I set up the environment variable `SECRET_KEY_BASE` as below in Vim editor.

```
-- INSERT --
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
        [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  # commands go here
fi
if [ -f /etc/profile ]; then
  # commands go here
fi
if [ -d /etc/profile.d -a -f /etc/profile ]; then
  # both are true

fi
if [ -d /etc/profile.d -o -f /etc/profile ]; then
  # at least one is true
fi

export SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED_CODE
```

I saved the above `SECRET_KEY_BASE` and ended Vim editor with the two below commands.

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

```
:q!
```

I opened the vim editor again as below with this command:`$ vi /etc/profile`.

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
        [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  # commands go here
fi
if [ -f /etc/profile ]; then
  # commands go here
fi
if [ -d /etc/profile.d -a -f /etc/profile ]; then
  # both are true

fi
if [ -d /etc/profile.d -o -f /etc/profile ]; then
  # at least one is true
fi

export SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED_CODE
```

I ran the following command.

```
$ vi ~/.bash_profile
```

I ran the following command in `~/.bash_profile`.

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED_CODE
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
"~/.bash_profile" 1L, 152B
```

I saved the above `SECRET_KEY_BASE` ,using <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then "`:x`" and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I verified that the environment variable `SECRET_KEY_BASE` is properly set up in Linux. Because I ran the three following command.

```
$ printenv | grep SECRET_KEY_BASE

SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED_CODE
```

```
$ echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE

GENERATED_CODE
```

```
$ heroku config

=== [My APP Name] Config Vars
DATABASE_PASSWORD: ****
DATABASE_URL: postgres://****
DATABASE_USERNAME: ****
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AQUA_URL: postgres://****
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK_URL: postgres://****
LANG: en_US.UTF-8
RACK_ENV: production
RAILS_ENV: production
RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT: enabled
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES: enabled
SECRET_KEY_BASE: GENERATED_CODE
```

I checked to see if there're an `/etc/profile.d` directory and an `/etc/profile` file. Because I ran the following command.

```
$ sudo ls -lh /etc/profile

-r--r--r--  1 DATABASE_USERNAME  wheel   599B Aug  8 15:08 /etc/profile
```

I ran the following command.

```
$ heroku open
```

The following error occured in the web browser.

```
An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.
```

I ran the following command.

```
$ heroku logs

#<RuntimeError: Missing
 `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`>
```

Why doesn't my rails application open? Even though I set up the environment variable 'SECRET_KEY_BASE' with the below commands.

```
$ heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE=GENERATED_CODE
```

```
$ vi /etc/profile
```

```
$ vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Maybe it is a capitalization issue. The config contains `SECRET_KEY_BASE:` but the error in the logs referenced `secret_key_base`.